# How to add an argument to pubsub callback

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using the pubsub library to publish messages to certain topics:

```
# init publisher
publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient(credentials=credentials)

# publish iteratively and keep track of the original iter id
for iter in [0,1,2,3,4]:
   message_future = self.publisher.publish(topic_path)
   message_future.add_done_callback(callback)

# callback
def callback(message_future):
   print(message_future)
   # how can I capture here the original "iter"?
```

However, I would like to add some meta data like:

```
message_future.add_done_callback(callback(message_future, iter=iter))
```

While this works, I receive after the function completes the error:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable 
>   line 149, in add_done_callback

What is happening?

See also:
https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/latest/publisher/index.html

Comment: Check the answer now @JohnAndrews

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are expected to pass a function in the `add_done_callback`.

```py
def foo():
    print('hello')

message_future.add_done_callback(foo)
```

Inside the add_done_callback, the function gets executed like this

```py
def add_done_callback(self, func):
    ...
    func(self)
```

The problem is that you're evaluating the callback function before passing it (`message_future.add_done_callback(foo()`), and your callback function returns None. So the message is trying to execute the None object and hence the error.

You can create a Callable class to store all your metadata as class members and then use it inside the callback function.

```py
class Callable:
  def __init__(self, idx):
    self.idx = idx

  def callback(self, message_future):
    print(message_future)
    print(self.idx)

# publish iteratively and keep track of the original iter id
for iter in [0,1,2,3,4]:
  callable = Callable(iter)
  message_future = self.publisher.publish(topic_path)
  message_future.add_done_callback(callable.callback)
```

Comment: wont work as I want to pass a parameter before the exection of the request

Comment: What do you mean by that? The callback only gets executed once the future event is done!

Comment: Yes but I am running pubsub request with parameters, and I want to include those when callback done so I know which id corresponds to settings of my request. I used example test='hello' but it could be also an id before.

Comment: You can get the id from message_future's result, right? Can you tell me an example of parameters that you want to pass to the callback?

Comment: Can you provide an example with the use case that force you to perform this kind of architecture?

Comment: I updated my question to provide an example. I am passing an iter id, that loops and off course finishes earlier. However, I want to capture this in the callback as I pass the argument.